# Neo4j - Set in a foreach never end

Tags: neo4j

I have a database that represents a map of a city for a school project.
Each node represent a point in a street, and each relationship represents a section of road, with the distance between the two nodes as a property.
I import it into Neo4j by parsing a XML file with a java interface.
But because of the way the XML file is encoded, I have a lot of node that are not useful because they just represent an intermediate position in the street, without being an intersection or indicating a new street.

So, I'm trying to take the extremity of each section of road between two intersection, create one relationship between those two nodes, and then sum the distance of each relationship of the street.

For each of those command, I use the browser client of neo4j, but with a database that is on my computer.
First of all, I mark all the relationships and nodes I want to destroy with this command:

```
match ()-[r]-(n)-[t]-()
with r,n,t,size(n--()) as degree
where degree=2 and r.name=t.name
set r.toDestroy=1,t.toDestroy=1,n.toDestroy=1
```

Then I get each pair of important nodes with

```
match (a)-[r* {toDestroy;1}]-(b)
where a.toDestroy is NULL and b.toDestroy is NULL and all (x in r where x.name=(r[0]).name)
return a,r,b
```

This command return what I ask for, so now I create a new relationships between (a) and (b), and set its distance

```
match (a)-[r* {toDestroy;1}]-(b)
where a.toDestroy is NULL and b.toDestroy is NULL and all (x in r where x.name=(r[0]).name)
merge (a)-[t:TRONCON_DE_VOIE]->(b)
set t.distance=0,t.name=(r[0]).name
foreach(x in r|set t.distance=t.distance+r.distance)
```

And here is where my problem is: This request never return, the client just tell me it's running. I don't understand why, because even if I isolate two nodes and their link, it doesn't work. And if I put something like (`set x.distance=1`) in the foreach, it doesn't work either.

I looked a bit on the internet, and nobody seems to have the same problem as me. Furthermore, if I create another DB and fill it with random nodes and try a similar command, it does end. So it may come from the DB itself, but I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because the last clause is going to call `SET` N times, where N is essentially the total number of relationships that have `toDestroy: 1`.

Here is a much more efficient query that uses no `SET` clauses at all:

```
MATCH (a)-[r* {toDestroy:1}]-(b)
WHERE a.toDestroy is NULL AND b.toDestroy is NULL AND ALL(x in r where x.name=(r[0]).name)
WITH a, b, (r[0]).name AS name, REDUCE(s = 0, x IN r | s + x.distance) AS total
merge (a)-[t:TRONCON_DE_VOIE {distance: total, name: name}]->(b);
```

Basically, you should always try to do calculations in memory, without storing temporary values in the DB.

[EDIT]

By the way, variable-length path searches can easily "run forever" and/or run out of memory, because they have exponential complexity. If the average number of relationships for each node along the path is `R`, and the depth of the search is `d`, then the number of different paths is roughly `R^d`. So, generally, you want to limit the depth of a variable-length path search by specifying an acceptably "small" upper bound, as in:

```
MATCH (a)-[r*..10 {toDestroy:1}]-(b)
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, it allowed me to solve my problem. But for the record, the query you gave don't work either, but if you put [r*1..10 {toDestroy:1}] it does work, for reason I don't really understand at the moment.

Comment: Variable-length path searches can easily "run forever" and/or run out of memory, because they have exponential complexity. If the average number of relationships for each node along the path is `R`, and the depth of the search is `d`, then the number of different paths is roughly `R^d`. So, generally, you want to limit the depth of a variable-length path search. I will add this to my answer.